# Copy as Response body dynamic value in xml

Tags: json, xml, xpath, paw-app

When working with XML responses I dont have the option to Copy as Response body dynamic value? 
Is this facility only available with JSON?

UPDATE-1:
Can't seem to get it working

I can add the Request object but the Key Path (dotted xpath) to the desired data is not giving the expected results. I am using "plan.link"

So the xml is like this

```
<plan>
  <id>7286</id>
  <piuid>1</piuid>
  <title>Bollard Positions</title>
  <link>http://<my-server-name>/port/1/plan/7286.gif</link>
</plan>
```

And I want to pick the url from the link element (plan.link)

But Paw is not reading right and changes the request to

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: echo.paw.cloud
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/3.1.3 (Macintosh; OS X/10.11.6) GCDHTTPRequest
```

I'm doing something wrong but not sure what.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

That's true, sadly you cannot just right-click and pick Copy as **Response Body Dynamic Value** for XML responses (only works for JSON and Form URL-Encoded).

Though, you can manually set a dynamic value to point to this field.

1. Right-click on a field where you want to insert this reference, and choose Response > Response Parsed Body

[image: Response Parsed Body]

2. Enter the **Key Path** to the node you want to select, and end it with the `text` key to access the string's value.

[image]

3. Should be a working reference. You can have the preview below.

Comment: I have expanded the question now

Comment: I think you're missing the `text` key I mentioned in step (2) above. You may try with the key path: `plan.link.text`. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thats it. Now, can I make an environment variable equal to a Response Parsed Body item?  So that I can use the variable in the definitions, but change the value of that variable based on the value in another response?

Comment: OK. Just figured out how to do that. I see I can do ordinal filtering in the Key Path, but, especially with xml, can I do other xpath filtering? So, I can do `ports.port[11].piuid.text` but what about `ports.port[flag=1][4].piuid` - is this syntax documented somewhere?

Comment: No we don't support the full XPath features. For now you can only filter via keys and indexes. We're going to add support for XPath later on.